# Is it possible to write a function that can dump arbitrary dimensional int array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Finally if I want to dump the array, just:

```
int array[dim1][dim2]..;

A(array, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4...);
```

Is it possible in C?

**UPDATE**

How to define the type of `array` in `A(array, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4...);` so that compiler won't give any warnings?

Comment: What do you mean "dump"? Save to file? Print to screen? Since arrays are stored contiguously, you can treat the multidimensional array as a one-dimensional array containing the same elements in major order according to earlier dimensions.

Comment: Just print to screen.Is it possible to make the function signature accept arbitrary dimensional array: `A(array, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4...);` ?

Comment: It's possible, but you may have to add an argument telling you the number of dimensions.

Comment: If C allows parameter lists (which it has to, right, since this is how printf works), yes. The first param is the array, and all other ones are dimensions. To print, just treat the array like it's one-dimensional, loop from 0 to the product of dimensions, and if you need coordinates, compute them for the 1-D index.

Comment: @jswolf19 ,how? It seems it will report a warning.

Comment: @Thomas Carpenter,the problem is there seems no correct type for arbitrary dimensional array.

Comment: @new-perl Could you please explain it more clearly What your trying to do what you want us to do?

Comment: Are you trying to walk every element in a static multidimensional array (which is really a linear array) or a dynamic one?

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes

The call to A must indicate the number of dimensions, and provide the size of each dimension.  Using some C99:

#### Code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void A(int *base, int ndims, ...);
extern void B(void);

void A(int *base, int ndims, ...)
{
    assert(ndims > 0);
    int     dims[ndims];
    int     size = 1;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, ndims);
    for (int i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
    {
        dims[i] = va_arg(args, int);
        size *= dims[i];
    }
    va_end(args);
    int mods[ndims];
    // I suspect this 'mods' loop is suboptimal, but it works.
    for (int i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
    {
        int v = size;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            v /= dims[j];
            mods[i] = v;
        }
    }
    for (int offset = 0; offset < size; offset++)
    {
        printf("%s", "array");
        for (int i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
        {
            int p = offset / mods[i];
            printf("[%d]", p % dims[i]);
        }
        printf(" = %d\n", base[offset]);
    }
}

void B(void)
{
    enum { dim1 = 4, dim2 = 6 };
    int array1[dim1][dim2] =
    {
        {  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
        { 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17 },
        { 32, 31, 30, 39, 38, 37 },
        { 42, 41, 40, 49, 48, 47 },
    };
    int array2[dim2][dim1][dim2] =
    {
        {
            { 15, 68, 67, 16, 105,  4 },
            { 25, 58, 67, 16, 115,  4 },
            { 35, 48, 67, 16, 125,  4 },
            { 45, 38, 67, 16, 135,  4 },
        },
        {
            { 19, 69, 77, 16, 205,  5 },
            { 29, 59, 77, 16, 215,  5 },
            { 39, 49, 77, 16, 225,  5 },
            { 49, 39, 77, 16, 235,  5 },
        },
        {
            { 12, 64, 87, 16, 305,  6 },
            { 22, 54, 87, 16, 315,  6 },
            { 32, 44, 87, 16, 325,  6 },
            { 42, 34, 87, 16, 335,  6 },
        },
        {
            { 17, 63, 97, 16, 405,  7 },
            { 27, 53, 67, 16, 415,  7 },
            { 37, 43, 97, 16, 425,  7 },
            { 47, 33, 97, 16, 435,  7 },
        },
        {
            { 10, 60, 90, 10, 500, 97 },
            { 20, 50, 60, 20, 510, 87 },
            { 30, 40, 90, 30, 520, 77 },
            { 40, 30, 90, 40, 530, 67 },
        },
        {
            { 11, 63, 97, 36, 605, 39 },
            { 21, 53, 67, 46, 615, 38 },
            { 31, 43, 97, 56, 625, 27 },
            { 41, 33, 97, 66, 635, 26 },
        },
    };
    A(&array1[0][0],    2, dim1, dim2);
    putchar('\n');
    A(&array2[0][0][0], 3, dim2, dim1, dim2);
}

int main(void)
{
    B();
    return(0);
}
```

#### Example output

```
array[0][0] = 0
array[0][1] = 1
array[0][2] = 2
array[0][3] = 3
array[0][4] = 4
array[0][5] = 5
array[1][0] = 22
array[1][1] = 21
array[1][2] = 20
array[1][3] = 19
array[1][4] = 18
array[1][5] = 17
array[2][0] = 32
array[2][1] = 31
array[2][2] = 30
array[2][3] = 39
array[2][4] = 38
array[2][5] = 37
array[3][0] = 42
array[3][1] = 41
array[3][2] = 40
array[3][3] = 49
array[3][4] = 48
array[3][5] = 47

array[0][0][0] = 15
array[0][0][1] = 68
array[0][0][2] = 67
array[0][0][3] = 16
array[0][0][4] = 105
array[0][0][5] = 4
array[0][1][0] = 25
array[0][1][1] = 58
array[0][1][2] = 67
array[0][1][3] = 16
array[0][1][4] = 115
array[0][1][5] = 4
array[0][2][0] = 35
array[0][2][1] = 48
array[0][2][2] = 67
array[0][2][3] = 16
array[0][2][4] = 125
array[0][2][5] = 4
array[0][3][0] = 45
array[0][3][1] = 38
array[0][3][2] = 67
array[0][3][3] = 16
array[0][3][4] = 135
array[0][3][5] = 4
array[1][0][0] = 19
array[1][0][1] = 69
array[1][0][2] = 77
array[1][0][3] = 16
array[1][0][4] = 205
array[1][0][5] = 5
array[1][1][0] = 29
array[1][1][1] = 59
array[1][1][2] = 77
array[1][1][3] = 16
array[1][1][4] = 215
array[1][1][5] = 5
array[1][2][0] = 39
array[1][2][1] = 49
array[1][2][2] = 77
array[1][2][3] = 16
array[1][2][4] = 225
array[1][2][5] = 5
array[1][3][0] = 49
array[1][3][1] = 39
array[1][3][2] = 77
array[1][3][3] = 16
array[1][3][4] = 235
array[1][3][5] = 5
array[2][0][0] = 12
array[2][0][1] = 64
array[2][0][2] = 87
array[2][0][3] = 16
array[2][0][4] = 305
array[2][0][5] = 6
array[2][1][0] = 22
array[2][1][1] = 54
array[2][1][2] = 87
array[2][1][3] = 16
array[2][1][4] = 315
array[2][1][5] = 6
array[2][2][0] = 32
array[2][2][1] = 44
array[2][2][2] = 87
array[2][2][3] = 16
array[2][2][4] = 325
array[2][2][5] = 6
array[2][3][0] = 42
array[2][3][1] = 34
array[2][3][2] = 87
array[2][3][3] = 16
array[2][3][4] = 335
array[2][3][5] = 6
array[3][0][0] = 17
array[3][0][1] = 63
array[3][0][2] = 97
array[3][0][3] = 16
array[3][0][4] = 405
array[3][0][5] = 7
array[3][1][0] = 27
array[3][1][1] = 53
array[3][1][2] = 67
array[3][1][3] = 16
array[3][1][4] = 415
array[3][1][5] = 7
array[3][2][0] = 37
array[3][2][1] = 43
array[3][2][2] = 97
array[3][2][3] = 16
array[3][2][4] = 425
array[3][2][5] = 7
array[3][3][0] = 47
array[3][3][1] = 33
array[3][3][2] = 97
array[3][3][3] = 16
array[3][3][4] = 435
array[3][3][5] = 7
array[4][0][0] = 10
array[4][0][1] = 60
array[4][0][2] = 90
array[4][0][3] = 10
array[4][0][4] = 500
array[4][0][5] = 97
array[4][1][0] = 20
array[4][1][1] = 50
array[4][1][2] = 60
array[4][1][3] = 20
array[4][1][4] = 510
array[4][1][5] = 87
array[4][2][0] = 30
array[4][2][1] = 40
array[4][2][2] = 90
array[4][2][3] = 30
array[4][2][4] = 520
array[4][2][5] = 77
array[4][3][0] = 40
array[4][3][1] = 30
array[4][3][2] = 90
array[4][3][3] = 40
array[4][3][4] = 530
array[4][3][5] = 67
array[5][0][0] = 11
array[5][0][1] = 63
array[5][0][2] = 97
array[5][0][3] = 36
array[5][0][4] = 605
array[5][0][5] = 39
array[5][1][0] = 21
array[5][1][1] = 53
array[5][1][2] = 67
array[5][1][3] = 46
array[5][1][4] = 615
array[5][1][5] = 38
array[5][2][0] = 31
array[5][2][1] = 43
array[5][2][2] = 97
array[5][2][3] = 56
array[5][2][4] = 625
array[5][2][5] = 27
array[5][3][0] = 41
array[5][3][1] = 33
array[5][3][2] = 97
array[5][3][3] = 66
array[5][3][4] = 635
array[5][3][5] = 26
```

Comment: it was actually easier to get the 3D case right and then specialize to the 2D case than to get the 2D case right and then generalize to the 3D case.

---

Note that this technique works for any contiguous array (like the statically allocated example).  There are ways of dynamically allocating arrays where the data is not contiguous, and this will not work on such pseudo-arrays.  This is a problem if you allocate an array of pointers, and each pointer then points to a vector of integers, or any similar scheme.  Such 'arrays' can be accessed using the double subscript notation, but the code generated is quite different from accessing a true multi-dimensional (contiguous) array.

The code in function `A()` won't handle an 'array' allocated like this (error checking omitted for brevity), even though the initialization loop looks much the same as an initialization loop for a regular (contiguous) 2D array:

```
int **base = malloc(4 * sizeof(*base));
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    base[i] = malloc(6 * sizeof(*base[i]));

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        base[i][j] = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    free(base[i]);
free(base);
```

Comment: In the static case, as I explained in the comments to my response, you can do a straight loop by multiplying all of the dimensions together and just walk, casting the array to an int*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to inspect a variable argument list and get the size, so you have to pass a length argument.

Here's a recursive example that can support arbitrary dimensional int array:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_array_v(void *a, int cnt, va_list args) {
    va_list nw;
    int i, j;
    i = va_arg(args, int);
    if(cnt > 1) {
            for(j=0; j != i; ++j) {
                    va_copy(nw, args);
                    printf("[%d %d]\n", cnt-1, j);
                    print_array_v(((int **)a)[j], cnt - 1, nw);
                    va_end(nw);
            }
    } else {
            printf("(%d, %p) ", i, a);
            for(j = 0; j != i; ++j) { printf("%d ", ((int *)a)[j]); }
            printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_array(void *a, int cnt, ...) {
    va_list lst;
    va_start(lst, cnt);        
    print_array_v(a, cnt, lst);
    va_end(lst);
}
```

Here is a sample driver:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
int i,j,k,l;
l = 0;
int ***a = malloc(2 * sizeof(int **));
for (i=0;i!=2;++i) {
    a[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    for(j=0;j!=2;++j) { 
        a[i][j] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        for(k=0;k!=2;++k) {
            a[i][j][k] = ++l;
            printf("(%d %d %d) %d\n", i, j, k, a[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
print_array(a, 3, 2, 2, 2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code only seems to work on arrays which are allocated as shown.  When run on a contiguous array, it crashes (at least, it did for me).  I bolted your code into my code, and ran yours on my 2D array, and it gave a segmentation fault.  (I agree your code works on the multiple-allocation arrays.  Well done on that.)

Comment: That's because static multidimensional arrays are really linear arrays with some arithmetic magic.  To prove it, try doing something simple like `int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}}; printf("%d\n", ((int *)a)[2]);`.  The question asked for arbitrary dimensional int array, which I interpreted to have to have been dynamically allocated.  A true N-dimensional array, by contrast, is really a linear array of pointers to (N-1)-dimensional arrays.

Comment: So is your 'contiguous or not' comment accurate? I think not.